# How to switch the Emojis on 19.10 (gnome)?

Tags: gnome, fonts

While I have working Noto Colour Emojis out of the box, I want to use "Blobmoji" instead. I already have the ttf installed in /usr/share/fonts/truetype/blobmoji/.

I tried modifying ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf, but whichever modification I made ruined the font in the top bar, so I made that file blank.

What exactly should I do to change the emoji font everywhere (including Chrome), without ruining the Gnome top bar?